# Loading vector only for specific zoom using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, vector

I have a map with 4-5 vectors. At the beginning, the loading of the web application is very very slow, but was fine before I've added a new one vector, which is used only for little zooms.

**Is it possible to launch the loading of a vector only when the specific zoom is reached?**

I'm currently using OpenLayers **2.2**, and as a beginner in OpenLayers, the only way I found to load a vector was like this:

```
var olmap = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM({
                url: 'php/map/getOsm.php?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}'
            })
        }), vector, vector_country, vector_countryName, vector_term, vector_port, vector_ramp
    ],
    renderer: ol.RendererHint.CANVAS,
    overlays: [overlay],
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.FullScreen(), new app.CustomExport()
    ]),
    view: mapView
});
```

---

That was quite easy :

```
olmap.addLayer(nameofthelayer);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may or may not help you. You could try the Map zoomend event and then do what you desire when the zoom level changes.

```
MAP.events.register("zoomend", this, function(e) {
var zoom = MAP.getZoom();
    // do something
});
```